# kafka: Commit offsets failed with retriable exception. You should retry committing offsets

Tags: java, apache-kafka

> [o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator] [Auto offset commit failed for group
>   consumer-group: Commit offsets failed with retriable
>   exception. You should retry committing offsets.] []

Why does this error come in kafka consumer? what does this mean?

The consumer properties I am using are:

```
fetch.min.bytes:1
enable.auto.commit:true
auto.offset.reset:latest
auto.commit.interval.ms:5000
request.timeout.ms:300000
session.timeout.ms:20000
max.poll.interval.ms:600000
max.poll.records:500
max.partition.fetch.bytes:10485760
```

What is the reason for that error to come? I am guessing the consumer is doing duplicated work right now (polling same message again) because of this error.

I am neither using `consumer.commitAsync()` or `consumer.commitSync()`

Comment: Hi, did you managed to fix this issue? Would be nice to know how.

Comment: Hey @ViacheslavShalamov, I am sure this is a late reply. I was not able to fix the issue. I had to restart the broker! Still hoping to be able to find the cause whenever it appears again :p

Comment: `enable.auto.commit:true` calls commitAsync under the hood, so it's the reason why you are getting this error

Comment: of course. but isn't that the point of `enable.auto.commit:true`? if SDK is managing the commit then why the developer has to face `Commit offsets failed with retriable exception. You should retry committing offsets`? I was hoping that using auto-commit we shouldn't worry about offset management.

Answer (score 4):

Consumer gives this error in case if it catches an instance of `RetriableException`.

The reasons for it might be various:

- if coordinator is still loading the group metadata
- if the group metadata topic has not been created yet
- if network or disk corruption happens, or miscellaneous disk-related or network-related IOException occurred when handling a request
- if server disconnected before a request could be completed
- if the client's metadata is out of date
- if there is no currently available leader for the given partition
- if no brokers were available to complete a request

As you can see from the list above, all these errors *could* be temporary issues, that is why it is suggested to retry the request.